# LINQ Optimization for searching a if an object exist in a list within a list

Tags: c#, linq, collections

Currently I have 7,000 video entries and I have a hard time optimizing it to search for Tags and Actress.

This is my code I am trying to modify, I tried using HashSet. It is my first time using it but I don't think I am doing it right.

```
        Dictionary dictTag = JsonPairtoDictionary(tagsId,tagsName);
        Dictionary dictActresss = JsonPairtoDictionary(actressId, actressName);
        var listVid =  new List<VideoItem>(db.VideoItems.ToList());
        HashSet<VideoItem> lll = new HashSet<VideoItem>(listVid);
        foreach (var tags in dictTag)
        {
            lll = new HashSet<VideoItem>(lll.Where(q => q.Tags.Exists(p => p.Id == tags.Key))); 
        }
        foreach (var actress in dictActresss)
        {
            listVid = listVid.Where(q => q.Actress.Exists(p => p.Id == actress.Key)).ToList(); 
        }
```

First part I get all the Videos in Db by using `db.VideoItems.ToList()`

Then it  will go through a loop to check if a Tag exist

For each VideoItem it has a `List<Tags>` and I use 'exist' to check if a tag is match.

Then same thing with Actress.

I am not sure if its because I am in Debug mode and ApplicationInsight is active but it is slow. And I will get like 10-15 events per second with `baseType:RemoteDependencyData` which I am not sure if it means it still connected to database (should not be since I only should only be messing with the a new list of all videos) or what.

After 7 mins it is still processing and that's the longest time I have waited.

I am afraid to put this on my live site since this will eat up my resource like candy

Comment: Do you need to match all tags or any tag?

Comment: What kind of database are you pulling from?  What is the type of `db.VideoItems`?  I would absolutely NOT pull all videos via ToList() and then filter down with LINQ - I'd use LINQ to build an intelligent query, using items that were indexed in the database, and then only use LINQ to Objects if you need to do very advanced filtering that your data provider can't do.

Comment: I tried  'db.VideoItems.Where(q=> q.Tags.Exists(p=>p.Id == 90));' 
#90 is  just a sample Tag that I am testing. 

And it was a lot faster, I think my problem was putting the load of search in the server not in the database. 

Now my problem is how can I iterate the process (for loop in my code) because I might expect 2 or 3 tags also the actress code.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of optimizing the linq you should optimize your database query.** 
Databases are great at optimized searches and creating subsets and will most likely be faster than anything you write. If you have need to create a subset based on more than on database parameter I would recommend looking into creating some indexes and using those.

**Edit:**

Example of db query that would eliminate first for loop (which is actually multiple nested loops and where the time delay comes from):

```
select * from videos where tag in [list of tags]
```

**Edit2**

To make sure this is most efficient, require the database to index on the TAGS column. To create the index:

```
CREATE INDEX video_tags_idx ON videos (tag)
```

Use 'explains' to see if the index is being used automatically (it should be)

```
explain select * from videos where tag in [list of tags]
```

If it doesn't show your index as being used you can look up the syntax to force the use of it.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you give examples considering in my scenario?

Comment: Look at `Contains`.

Comment: Can you give me a reason why you would use Contains over IN?

Comment: I think contains will find the same object, not sure in this context though. 

Thanks BoldAsLove. Will try it if it will reduced the execution time

Comment: Linq query `Contains` Translate to `IN` in SQL (if run against database).

Comment: I figured, just realize that the tag that's comparing in the code is the object tag and not its ID.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not optimization but it was utilization of the Microsoft SQL or my ApplicationDbContext.

I found this when I realize that http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Because the problem with Keyword search, there can be multiple keywords, and the code I made above doesn't utilize the SQL which made the long execution time.

Using the predicate builder, it will be possible to create dynamic conditions in LINQ